# Como pegar o tempo do sistema e somar minutos a ele em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, data

Estou fazendo uma "calculadora" básica para um jogo, e preciso de uma função que pegue a data do sistema e adicione 30 minutos quando o botão for pressionado.
Segue o Script que estou tentando usar e não dá certo:

```
function time() {
    var today = new Date();
    h = today.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    m = today.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    s = today.getSeconds();
    min = m + 30;
    document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = h + ":" + min + ":" + s;
}
```

Ao executar fica assim:

[image: ele apenas concatena]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) retorna uma string, e quando você "soma" uma string com um número, está na verdade concatenando o número na string:

```js
let s = '12'; // "s" é uma string
console.log(s + 30); // 1230
```

Então na verdade você tem que somar os 30 minutos **antes** de transformar tudo em string:

```js
function time() {
    let today = new Date();
    today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 30);
    let h = today.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let m = today.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let s = today.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
}
```

```html
<p id="texto"></p>
<button onclick="time()">vai</button>
```

Repare também que somei os 30 minutos usando [`setMinutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes). Isso porque se você simplesmente somar ao retorno de [`getMinutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) pode obter resultados errados. Por exemplo, se for 17:50, `getMinutes` vai retornar 50, e você soma 30, o resultado será 80 e a hora seria mostrada como 17:80 - usando o *setter*, ele já ajusta para a hora seguinte e o resultado é 18:20).

---

E uma outra opção para formatar o horário é usar [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```js
function time() {
    let today = new Date();
    today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 30);
    document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = today.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
}
```

```html
<p id="texto"></p>
<button onclick="time()">vai</button>
```

No caso, "pt-BR" corresponde ao português do Brasil, cujo formato de horas é justamente o que você precisa (hh:mm:ss).

---

Outra opção - caso queira/possa usar uma lib externa - é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
function time() {
    document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = moment().add(30, 'minutes').format('HH:mm:ss');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>

<p id="texto"></p>
<button onclick="time()">Vai</button>
```

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado mesmo, algo tão simples, e eu quebrando a cabeça.